# Frontend editing in Joomla doesn't work

Tags: joomla, editor, joomla2.5, frontend

I have made a site in Joomla 2.5, and can't edit my articles by using the frontend option "edit article".
This function is available when I am running the site in offline mode, but when I switch to online mode, it disappears.
When running the site in online mode, I login to the administrator, and then "view site"
Can some one please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to log in on the frontend when your site is in online mode to be able to edit articles. It doesn't matter if you are logged already on the backend, it won't count.

You should either enable log in module on some page, or a menu item pointing to log in page on the frontend. After logging in there, you will be able to edit your articles.

If you don't want users to see your login page/module on the frontend, you can create a hidden menu item for it, for which only you would know the link and it won't be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your website's /index.php?option=com_users

There you will be able to login to the frontend.